# Chrome Canary or Multiple Chromes

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to run multiple chrome's so there are multiple icons on ubuntu?

Chrome canary is not available for Ubuntu.
Chromium can be buggy.

Comment: So you want to run two completely separate instances of Chrome?

Comment: @AndroidDev yes with having them separate icons.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Have you tried Chrome-Beta?

Comment: @PatrickNegus I'm trying Chrome-Dev right now see if that works.